# Powerpoint ppsx opens in edit mode

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, slideshow

I recently reinstalled on my laptop Windows7 64 bit OS. Along with it I reinstalled Office 2010 Home and Student Edition with a valid product key.

The problem is I am no longer able to open my ppsx and ppsm files in slideshow mode automatically (which was fine before I had the reinstallation). It now opens like it opens pptx files in edit mode. I also notice that in the past, ppsx, ppsm, pptx files all have slightly different powerpoint icons associated with them. Now they all are the same.

FYI, Excel is running okay. By that I mean I can see 2 slightly different icons for Macro-Enabled Workbook type and (the regular) Excel Workbook type.

I also checked in Control Panel under File Association that all these different powerpoint types are associated with powerpoint.exe, so no issues there.
When I try creating a new powerpoint file and save it as Powerpoint Show, the ppsx extension appears at the back of the filename but still opens in edit mode.

I understand this problem is rife when a ppsx file is attached in an email or shared via website but I am trying to open it from my own hard drive.

Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use the [FileTypeDiag](https://www.pretentiousname.com/miscsoft/#FileTypeDiag) utility and generate file type association dump for .ppsx and ppsm file types. Upload the output to Pastebin and share us the link.

Comment: Here are the links to Pastebin:                                  http://pastebin.com/3ZXGLKFy

Comment: This is for the ppsm type                                  http://pastebin.com/MFCsHiAh                                                             Thanks David.

Comment: @w32sh Just found out that I have to key in "@name" to have that persons' attention. I posted the files generated by FileTypeDiag in the previous comments.

Comment: Yes. Checked those logs before posting my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to the user account where the file association issue is seen. Open a Command Prompt window (`cmd.exe`) and run these commands:

```
reg delete HKCU\Software\Classes\.ppsm /f
```

Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
reg delete HKCU\Software\Classes\.ppsx /f
```

Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ppsx\UserChoice" /f
```

**Method 2: Create a REG file**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ppsx]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ppsm]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ppsx]
```

Copy the above lines to Notepad and save the file as `ppsfix.reg`. Double-click to run the file.

That should fix the problem.

Comment: ppsm type of files now show up as slideshow but ppsx type still opens in Edit mode. There are still mismatch in the icons though for these types of files. Whereas the icon in the FIle Association window for ppsm has changed, the icon for ppsx is still the same as that of pptx. However the icons of all three type of files (in deskop where I save them) are the same. Please see picture here: [FileAssociation_ppsx_ppsm.jpg](https://postimg.org/image/has3icrbz/). Is there a straightforward way to solve this?

Comment: I must add that the three types of files saved on Desktop when viewed in Windows Explorer are okay in that the ppsm icon is the same as that displayed in the File Association window (which is different from the ppsx and pptx type).

Comment: Pls run the 3rd command in my answer. I've added it now.

Comment: I've got the message "Error: Access is denied". Just to clarify, there is the "  characters before HKCU and after UserChoice, right?

Comment: Oh. Pls try Method 2. And you're correct about the double-quotes.

Comment: It worked. Both ppsm and ppsx opens as slideshow. The icons for ppsx however is still the same as that for pptx. That is a minor flaw. Is there a quick way to sort that out?

Comment: You can refresh the icons using [this method](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/refresh-icon-cache-windows-7-quickly/), or [this](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-incorrect-icon-shown-for-a-file-type/), or [this finally](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-rebuild-the-icon-cache-in-windows/).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Rules says no "thanks" in comments but I simply must thank you w32sh. You are awesome!

Comment: You're very welcome! Generally icons refresh after a restart. and if that doesn't happen, the cache may need to be refreshed/rebuilt.

Comment: I have one more minor issue with icons. It is not advisable to have long discussions in comments so I have posted my question here: http://superuser.com/questions/1133036/powerpoint-icons-appear-differently-in-different-size-setting    
Can you take a look please?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but think I have solved it. The problem started after recently updating my Office 365. None of my Powerpoint Show files (.ppsx or .pps) would open as Shows and all would open in Power Point as an edit file.

I went to the properties of a file saved as .ppsx which would open in Powerpoint in the edit mode instead of opening as a slide show.
In the Properties I went to Opens with, clicked Change then clicked on Powerpoint and clicked apply and OK.

I saw that the icon had changed slightly and saw that the icons of all my .ppsx and .pps files had slightly changed and all the .ppsx and .pps files now open as a slide show and no longer in Power Point as an edit file.

I do not know what happened but think that when you work in the latest Power Point and save the file as a .ppsx it really does not save it as a .ppsx but as a .pptx (as it says it must in the Options in the Powerpoint program!!). By resetting it’s Opens with afterwards in properties it has magically adopted the .ppsx and changed all the files with that suffix and with .pps to open as shows!  Think it bypasses the glitch in the actual programme where it states in Options – Save that it must save as a presentation with no alternative such as a show. To see this do the following:
In Power Point click on File then on Options then on Save in the window that opens. Then check under Save presentations and then next to Save files in this format there is a window which only has 5 choices for the user and they are all forms of Presentation but no mention of Show.  So despite you selecting to save it as a .ppsx it subliminally really saves it as a .pptx.  The file has a .ppsx suffix but only adopts it when Power Point is reselected in the properties of the file. It then automatically did all similar files on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue.  I was able to resolve it by going to the properties and selecting Powerpoint as the program to run that type of file.