# Display Powerpoint icons uniformly across view layouts?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, icons

The icons for Powerpoint files are display differently when viewed from different layouts.

When Small Icons are selected, the icons for .ppsx, .ppsm and .pptx types are all different.

This is normal but when Medium or Large Icons are selected, the icons for the aforementioned file types do not match those of the smaller size. However, files with .pps extension however displays the same in all size settings.

Example: [Powerpoint Icons](https://postimg.org/image/yjrfw647h/)

Is there a way to have the icons display uniformly across view layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the files without preview pictures.

1. Open your presentation and click the "File" tab.
2. Select "Advance Properties" from the "Property" tab.

[image]

3. Uncheck  "Save preview picture".

---

Both files in small and large thumbnail settings.

[image]
[image]

Presentation 1 is saved with previews. Presentation 2 is saved without previews.

Comment: It worked Carrein. Your help is most appreciated!